Stranded space battalion series
I once read a series about a space military battalion stranded on a less advanced planet. They became involved on one side of a local conflict.
The soldiers were marooned on the planet, not there intentionally; I don’t remember whether by accident or enemy action, but it was probably accidental. Likely failure of their transport.
Also the group may have been the size of a regiment and was equipped with armoured vehicles

Why don't you tell us about it, maybe we can help you find it. How long ago did you read it? What happens in the story?

Is this everything you remember? It seems like a lot of series would fit the description.

Makes me think of "March Upcountry" by Weber and Ringo

The mention of a battalion makes me think of A Small Colonial War by Robert Frezza, but the question needs more details before I'm comfortable posting it as an answer. It's not exactly an uncommon plot

Are you certain that the battalion were space soldiers? The Janissaries series by Jerry Pournelle begins with a 20th Century military group being taken from earth to work on a less advanced alien world.

L.E. Modesitt's Fall of Angels, surely.

How much "less advanced" was the planet?  Stone Age, Bronze/Iron Age, Early Modern, early/late Industrial...?  @Shawn doesn't really match Frezza's duology (which are favourites of mine), Vereschagin's and Uwe's battalions arrived and their transport departed on schedule, the subsequent loss of orbital fire support was not something that stranded them.  Only matching point is that they did have some light armoured vehicles, unlike most of the other suggestions.
